# Unsplash API OAuth error: The access token is invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am using the `/search/photos` endpoint of [Unsplash's API](https://unsplash.com/documentation#search-photos) to retrieve pictures given a specific query.

Here is the get request:

```
unsplash_request_url = "https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?query=#{query}&content_filter=high&client_id=#{ENV['UNSPLASH_ACCESS_KEY']}"

html = URI.open(unsplash_request_url)
return JSON.parse(Nokogiri::HTML(html.read))
```

As stated in the documentation, I pass the Access token I got with the `client_id` parameter.

However, I get the following error:

> OAuth error: The access token is invalid

I tried to remove the `client_id` parameter and add the access token in the Authorization header, but I get the same error.

Any idea how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are providing the access key and not the secret key to the endpoint.

I tested your code with an access key and it works fine.

Comment: I created a new app and the new access key works. I tried to get an answer from Unsplash but no news so far... I guess they canceled the old access key somehow.